# Apache ignit : Syntax error in SQL statement create table

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, spring-boot, ignite

I am looking to index my data apache ignite to then use spring data ignite.
But I have a problem when launching my project; ignite can not create the sql table.

I thought it could be a mistake in the property names but I varied the indexed properties and I always got the same error.

I use a database mongoDb, is that compatible with this feature?

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to register query type: QueryTypeDescriptorImpl [cacheName=CacheVehiculeImmat, name=VehiculeImmat, schemaName=CacheVehiculeImmat, tblName=VEHICULEIMMAT, fields={ID=class java.lang.String, OBJECTID=class java.lang.String}, idxs={VEHICULEIMMAT_OBJECTID_IDX=QueryIndexDescriptorImpl [name=VEHICULEIMMAT_OBJECTID_IDX, type=SORTED, inlineSize=-1], VEHICULEIMMAT_ID_IDX=QueryIndexDescriptorImpl [name=VEHICULEIMMAT_ID_IDX, type=SORTED, inlineSize=-1]}, fullTextIdx=null, keyCls=class java.lang.String, valCls=class java.lang.Object, keyTypeName=java.lang.String, valTypeName=com.persist.petiteflotte.model.VehiculeImmat, valTextIdx=false, typeId=51183916, affKey=null, keyFieldName=null, valFieldName=null, obsolete=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.registerType(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1709) ~[ignite-indexing-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.registerCache0(GridQueryProcessor.java:1512) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart0(GridQueryProcessor.java:779) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart(GridQueryProcessor.java:840) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:1113) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1816) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCachesOnLocalJoin(GridCacheProcessor.java:1681) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.initCachesOnLocalJoin(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:725) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:613) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2279) ~[ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110) [ignite-core-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ""CacheVehiculeImmat"".""VEHICULEIMMAT"" (_KEY VARCHAR INVISIBLE[*] NOT NULL,_VAL OTHER INVISIBLE,_VER OTHER INVISIBLE,""ID"" VARCHAR,""OBJECTID"" VARCHAR) ENGINE ""org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2TableEngine"" "; expected "(, FOR, UNSIGNED, NOT, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, NOT, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, IDENTITY, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE "CacheVehiculeImmat"."VEHICULEIMMAT" (_KEY VARCHAR INVISIBLE NOT NULL,_VAL OTHER INVISIBLE,_VER OTHER INVISIBLE,"ID" VARCHAR,"OBJECTID" VARCHAR) engine "org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2TableEngine" [42001-193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:537) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:3186) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIfMore(Parser.java:885) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:6043) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:4238) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:362) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:293) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:502) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:170) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2TableEngine.createTable(H2TableEngine.java:65) ~[ignite-indexing-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.createTable(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1784) ~[ignite-indexing-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.registerType(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1702) ~[ignite-indexing-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Here's my code:

```
CacheConfiguration cacheVehiculeImmat = new CacheConfiguration();
cacheVehiculeImmat.setName(CacheHash.CACHEVEHICULE);
cacheVehiculeImmat.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
cacheVehiculeImmat.setReadThrough(true);
cacheVehiculeImmat.setIndexedTypes(String.class, VehiculeImmat.class);
cacheVehiculeImmat.setWriteThrough(true);
cacheVehiculeImmat.setStoreKeepBinary(false);
cacheVehiculeImmat.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
cacheVehiculeImmat.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
Factory<SpringDataVehiculeDataStore> storeDataVehicule = FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(SpringDataVehiculeDataStore.class);
cacheVehiculeImmat.setCacheStoreFactory(storeDataVehicule);
```

My model:

```
@Document(collection = "vehicule")
    public class VehiculeImmat implements Serializable{
        @Id
        private String id=new ObjectId().toString();

        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        private String objectId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

My datastore:

```
public class SpringDataVehiculeDataStore extends CacheStoreAdapter<String, VehiculeImmat> implements LifecycleAware {

    private VehiculeRepository vehiculeRepository = null;

    @Override
    public VehiculeImmat load(String immat) throws CacheLoaderException {
        VehiculeImmat courtierEnterprise = vehiculeRepository.findByImmat(immat);
        return courtierEnterprise;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Cache.Entry<? extends String, ? extends VehiculeImmat> entry) throws CacheWriterException {
        VehiculeImmat vehiculeImmat = entry.getValue();
        vehiculeRepository.save(vehiculeImmat);
    }


    @Override
    public void delete(Object o) throws CacheWriterException {
        VehiculeImmat vehiculeImmat = vehiculeRepository.findByImmat(String.valueOf(o));
        vehiculeRepository.delete(vehiculeImmat);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws IgniteException {
        vehiculeRepository = AppContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(VehiculeRepository.class);
    }
    public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<String,VehiculeImmat> clo,
                          Object... args){
        for(VehiculeImmat vehiculeImmat:vehiculeRepository.findAll()) {
            clo.apply(vehiculeImmat.getImmat(),vehiculeImmat);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws IgniteException {

    }
}
```

Do you have an idea of the problem?

Comment: It's probably complaining about the `[*]` following `INVISIBLE`, because that is not valid according to the [H2 syntax](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition).

Comment: But how to remove that character, I never add it myself. An idea of what generates it?

Comment: Probably the `org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2TableEngine.createTable` method, so you'll have to talk to the Apache Ignite people.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an H2 version mismatch. Ignite 2.3 is built on top of H2 1.4.195. Howerver, in your stack trace I see version 1.4.193, which is incompatible with Ignite 2.3.

Please make sure that correct H2 version is used.

Comment: Why does the maven 2.3.0 ignite-indexing dependency then contain com.h2.database 1.4.193?
i tried to exclude it and add maven dependency 1..4.195 but i get an error> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.result.RowFactory

Comment: Ignite indexing and SQL depend on H2 database, it is a mandatory dependency, at least as of today.